Why do some frum Jews go to college, even though the Lubavitcher Rebbe writes that it's completely forbidden for all Jews forever?
B"H
This question is clearly NOT opinion based because it is only asking for any official published justification for college from any rav or rabbi in response to the very specific points mentioned in the sources. Nothing opinionated about it.
The Lubavitcher Rebbe writes that it was prohibited for Jews to go to college.
Letter:

It is therefore more obvious than ever that no Jew has a right to give
of his time, and even more so of his heart and mind, to matters which
not only do not help but are very likely to hinder in the fulfillment
of his sacred task and purpose. One of these matters would be to spend
several years in college, and especially in a college environment.
It is certain, however, that college will not help fulfill the true
and inner desire of the Jew to carry out his above mentioned task and
purpose in life, so that even at best it would be an irretrievable
loss of time and energy.
It is therefore my sincere hope that you will discard the idea, and do
so not only because — as you told your father — you wish to be guided
by me, but also because you will recognize that the idea does not
represent your own true thinking and desire. I hope, moreover, that
you will use your good influence in this direction with your friends
who might entertain a similar idea in the mistaken belief that it
might be a good idea.

Another:

I can therefore state with the fullest measure of conviction and
responsibility that he who sends his child to college during the
formative years subjects him to shock and profound conflicts and
trials and invites quite unforeseen consequences . . .
To put the matter in bolder relief, by way of illustration. Take the
general attitude to polio, G-d forbid, and the precaution taken
against it. Fortunately, the incidence of polio is not widespread, and
where it strikes, it cripples only a part of the physical body; yet
though the odds are farfetched it would be reckless not to take the
necessary precaution. Unfortunately, the victims of college education
are numerous indeed and most widespread, by far in the majority, and
the harm is even more far-reaching.

But nevertheless, there are still some Jews who claim to be Torah observant that are in universities.
How is this justified? Have any official rabbonim responded to the letters of the Rebbe?
Authoritative sources only.

It sounds like no matter whatever answer someone gives, it will not suffice, since it will contradict a prophetic statement according to you ..so not sure what you are trying to achieve

Is this a pashkevil or an actual question?

@sam authoritative sources for anyone trying to justify it . Not act question has to gain an answer that will charge one's view, I will always have the same view I have, but the purpose of this question is at least to try to understand the "other side", so I know how to properly refute them in the future. What I do with the information I gain is not the concern of anyone else here, but the question itself is still a valid question.

@Awtsmoos--עצמות ,everyone is entitled to their opinion, and I am not here to argue with anyone for that matter ,the question just comes off wrong . If you would remove the initial paragraph, I think you would have gotten some good response

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I've edited the question.  @shmosel, sam, and all:  Please consider retracting your downvotes.

I didn't downvote.

@unforgettableidSupportsMonica, I too did not downvote.  As originally drafted my answer began In an effort to provide an answer which may satisfy the OP and in an effort to avoid machloket and continued unpleasantness, can I draw the OP's attention to this pamphlet prepared "In an attempt to answer the often confusing and subtle questions that arise, especially in relation to Jewish or online colleges". However that wording was edited out.

Didn't the rebbe himself attend university?

@IsraelReader yes he did. What's your point?

If he himself attended university, then it sounds like a case of, "Do as I say, not as I do", which highlights inconsistency between one's advice and own actions.

@IsraelReader  a lot of things sound like a lot of things. The Rebbe is our command in chief, we listen only to what he says. If one wants to copy what he does, one can first learn the entire Torah, talmud (in iyun) , Torah ohr likutei Torah, lots of other chassidus, kol hatorah kula etc etc get married, then maybe after all that we can find a university with someone similar to Erwin Schrodinger as a professor, then maybe we can start to think about the possibly of having a discussion

Got it. Blindly following a "commander in chief", who preached what he didn't practice himself.

@IsraelReader the question is about what he said. Not what he did, not what his followers choose to react to what he did, not what others' opinions are about a Rebbe and chossid relationship. Just what he said about not going to college, and if any other rabbonim tried to justify college and respond to his letters. Nothing else.

This is only a small portion of what the Rebbe said about college. It's obvious from the many letters that were written that while he opposed college for the vast majority of bochrim that grew up in the lubavitch educational system it did not mean the Rebbe opposed it for everyone for example baale teshuva that were already enrolled in college were encouraged to finish rather than drop out. There were also notable individuals that were encouraged to get a degree such a rabbi Jonathan sachs who completed his PhD long before becoming a rabbi

@dude yes he did clearly oppose it for everyone. Only exceptions were people already enrolled they were sometimes told to finish their prison sentences. There were a few extremely rare exceptions where he told people to go initially, but those are in no way the rule.

In what world would the Lubavicher Rebbe’s opinion be binding over everyone? Why should I, a Mizrahi Jew whose family never encountered him, take his statements as Halacha? His writings, while obviously valuable, have no practical bearing on my practice. Your premise is not just faulty, but delusional.

Additionally, as I just discovered from some research, you took those statements entirely out of context! How can you claim to follow the Rebbe yet simultaneously twist his teachings? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Please see this pamphlet published on the website of N'shei Chabad:
https://asktherav.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/College-Booklet-Applying-the-Rebbes-Position.pdf
See also https://derher.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/College-Sivan-5777.pdf and https://collive.com/what-is-so-wrong-with-college/
It is best to read the pamphlet in full, but I will summarize it briefly:
At first, the pamphlet carefully considers (p. 3) “the Rebbe's statements about college.” It states (p. 3): "At the same time, in a changing world, understanding how the Rebbe’s position applies practically can be confusing. What would the Rebbe say today – sixty years later? Given the challenges of parnassa and the need for a degree for certain positions, would the Rebbe change his position? And what would the Rebbe say about Jewish colleges? What about online courses?"
This is the pamphlet's conclusion (p. 30) set out in full:
Conclusion
Before a Lubavitcher chossid considers pursuing a degree, he should make an honest cheshbon nefesh about what is right for him and his future family b’ruchniyus. After serious thought, several critical questions must be discussed with a qualified Rav and mashpia, who is well-versed in the pertinent issues:

Who am I? What is the Shlichus for which my neshama was sent to this world? What does it mean to me to be a chossid of the Rebbe?

Is now the appropriate time for me to be concerned with parnassa? Is it relevant? Is it necessary?

If parnassa is a current concern, what are the available options that do not involve a degree?

If a degree is deemed necessary, what are the options available that are the least problematic, both in the areas of environment and of the studies? Which institution? Which degree? Which courses?

Assuming there will remain concerns of טמטום המח והלב from the secular teachings no matter what, how can I minimize them? Can I counter the influence of secularism with a significant schedule of learning Chassidus and touching base regularly with the mashpia?


Unless absolutely necessary, college should be avoided until after the formative years (approximately age thirty), and especially until after marriage.

The pamphlet was clearly prepared with great care and with input from significant contemporary rabbis and others from Chabad. The Chabad rabbis named in the pamphlet as having reviewed it are:
•   R. Ezra Schochet – Los Angeles
•   R. Shmuel Bluming– Crown Heights
•   R. Levi Yitzchok Raskin – London, England
•   R. Yosef Braun – Crown Heights
•   R. Akiva Wagner – Toronto
•   R. Levi Jacobson – Toronto
•   R. Nochum Kaplan – Crown Heights
and the "invaluable assistance" of the following Chabad rabbis is acknowldged: R. Yehuda Leib Schapiro, R. Shmuly Avtzon, R. Mendel Blau, R. Yitzchok Meir Gurary, R. Shimon Hellinger.
In case there is any confusion the word "college" is used as a synonym for "university."

For a recent non-Chabad viewpoint see this article Is It Proper To Attend A Non-Jewish university? (Jewish Press May 15, 2024) Rabbi Zev Leff, Rabbi Jonathan Muskat and Rabbi Steven Pruzansky

Interesting. Basically the same thing, college is bad, in general don't go. For sure not university. Only if absolutely necessary maybe one can go to a Jewish "program". Not the same as college. The letters the Rebbe wrote are eternal. If they were true then they are true now. The other sources you cited say pretty clearly not to go. One of the main points was not to do any kind of trickery to a livelihood , only rely on Hashem directly

My understanding is that college is a synonym for university in American English. See https://www.studyusa.com/en/a/107/what-is-the-difference-between-a-school-college-and-university-in-the-usa#:~:text=You%20can%20earn%20a%20bachelor's,undergraduate%20programs%20and%20bachelor's%20degrees. You can earn a bachelor's degree at either a college or a university. However, students in the U.S.A. prefer to use the word "college" rather than the word "university" when they talk about four-year undergraduate programs and bachelor's degrees.

@Awtsmoos--עצמות I am sad that you conclude Basically the same thing, college is bad, in general don't go. The pamphlet was clearly prepared with great care and with input from significant contemporary rabbis and others from Chabad. I suggest that a better conclusion is MAYBE and Before a Lubavitcher chossid considers pursuing a degree, he should make an honest cheshbon nefesh about what is right for him and his future family b’ruchniyus. After serious thought, several critical questions must be discussed with a qualified Rav and mashpia, who is well-versed in the pertinent issues

A degree is not the same as college. That pamphlet is talking about only considering specific kinds of frum programs to get degrees. Not university. Not any kind of secular college for sure

@Awtsmoos--עצמות, being steadfast to radicalism isn’t helpful. Not to you, not to anyone around you, and not to Hashem. Use your brain.
